# web.py and flask

Tags: python

For these *pythonic* web frameworks;

They looks similar, except a few minor differences like their url handling schemes. So it is very hard to choose one of them.

I want to learn from your experiences that which one more suits for a web application that is small in size, but need long term support (initial application is small but it is supposed to became larger over time) and why?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Flask is a new and a very active project with good documentation and guidelines for new development and plugins. Its community is quite large and Armin (the lead) is an A grade programmer. Hence it is definitely the better contender.

Web.py is an older and more mature project which is more a library than a framework. It's what we use for the Internet Archives Open Library website. The documentation is spotty but the code is rock solid and it's over the years accrued a lot of useful utilities into it.

The final decision is yours but for a new project, I'd go with Flask.

Comment: +1 for the Flask documentation, not only about python stuff, but also about xhtml and html5 and hackers attacks (xss)...a MUST READ even if you'll not use Flaks ;)

Comment: +1 for Web.py simplicity & RESTful design.